# How to flag if a 'webform' exists on a page?

Tags: 7, webforms, flags

I an fairly new to Drupal and have a custom module in which I need to write some PHP logic. It needs to insert a flag basically, on any page which contains a 'webform' of any kind.

I see the webform api page, but I don't see anything which would just tell me if a webform is on a page.

I have tried this if statement to insert my little flag - but it is showing on every page.  I assume because drupal calls every `page` a `form`?  so technically my code bit is flagging every page?

```
if (function_exists(form_id)) {
    $variables['s.event4'] = "event4";
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi @sadiecolorado, welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you add the Drupal core version you're using as a tag? So "7" for Drupal 7 and "8" for Drupal 8. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code being executed? In a hook_form_alter() or a template_preprocess()? Also, form_id is not a function. You would want something like !empty($form_id).

Comment: Hello Wim, - I am on 7.  I'm sorry, I'm not great at Drupal yet.  I dont think the code is being executed in a template_preprocess. I see things like this in the code (someone elses custom module)  // Initialize a variables array to be returned by this hook.
  $variables = array();

Comment: Hi Mirakolous - ok thank you, I didn't know form_id wasn't a function of its own.  So for your example of !empty($form_id), would that work in my situation?  If I'm understanding you correctly, that is a proper way to use the variable, but is not applicable to finding if a webform itself is on the page?  I don't have the right variable yet I assume?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a preprocess function. If it's hook_preprocess_page(), you can do this:

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'webform')
  {
    $variables['s.event4'] = "event4";
  }
}
```